# Querying multiple tables in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

As it is not possible to update data within a table in BigQuery, and supports only append mechanism, I have decided to create new tables on monthly basis. So suppose for year 2012 the tables would be (`tbl_012012`, `tbl_022012`, `tbl_032012`,...`tbl_122012`). Each record will be stored along with date `timestamp` as string.

Now, if my application wants to fetch records ranging from Jan 2012(`tbl_012012`) to March 2012(`tbl_032012`), will BigQuery API automatically traverse through the desired tables via single SQL range query or will I have to write multiple SQL queries with extra application code to retrieve each query result and then aggregate them altogether?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One SQL query can reference multiple tables. Just separate each table with a comma in the FROM clause to query across all mentioned tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for. But this will work in case of range queries, what if  my query searches for a single record that can be redundant. So in this case Big Query will obviously traverse through every month table to find that record.

Comment: BigQuery is optimized for aggregate queries, as opposed to queries which are searching for a single record.  So, yes, unfortunately in this case you'd need to search through every month table if you're looking for just a single record which could be in any of the tables.

Answer (score 40):

You can also use a Table Wildcard Function. Here's one example from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference) for StandardSQL:

```
SELECT 
  name
FROM 
  mydata.people
WHERE 
  age >= 35
  AND
  (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20140325' AND '20140327')
```

And here's a similar example for LegacySQL ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions)).

```
SELECT 
  name
FROM 
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.people], 
                TIMESTAMP('2014-03-25'), 
                TIMESTAMP('2014-03-27'))) 
WHERE 
  age >= 35
```

This will query the tables:

- mydata.people20140325
- mydata.people20140326
- mydata.people20140327

There are a few other options on the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference). I'd recommend checking them out.

Comment: Is it possible to query a month range of form `201601` as well?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a snippet demonstrating an example of the multiple table select:

```
SELECT trafficSource.medium AS Traffic_Source, COUNT(trafficSource.medium) AS Counts_Source
FROM [608XXXXX.ga_sessions_20131008],
[608XXXXX.ga_sessions_20131009],
[608XXXXX.ga_sessions_20131010],
[608XXXXX.ga_sessions_20131011],
[608XXXXX.ga_sessions_20131012],
[608XXXXX.ga_sessions_20131013],
[608XXXXX.ga_sessions_20131014],
[608XXXXX.ga_sessions_20131015],
GROUP BY Traffic_Source
ORDER BY Counts_Source DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

2017 update:

With BigQuery #standardSQL - you can either use standard `UNION ALL` to go through multiple tables, or you can use a `*` to match all tables that share the same prefix. When using the `*` matcher, you will also have access to the meta-column `_TABLE_SUFFIX` - to know which table the rows came from.

```
SELECT * FROM Roster
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TeamMascot
```

Answer (score 1):

## Standard SQL.

Use a wildcard.

```
SELECT trafficSource.medium AS Traffic_Source, COUNT(trafficSource.medium) AS Counts_Source
FROM `608XXXXX.ga_sessions_201310*`
GROUP BY Traffic_Source
ORDER BY Counts_Source DESC
```