# Big Query multiple tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query from multiple tables in Google's BigQuery. I am getting the error "Field 'w.max_temperature' not found in table 'weather.stations'."

Here is my SQL:

`SELECT w.station_number, s.LAT, s.LON, w.year, w.month, avg(w.mean_temp) as [mean temp], max(w.max_temperature) as [max temp], min(w.min_temperature) as [min temp], avg(w.mean_visibility) as [avg visbility]
FROM [weather.stations] s, [publicdata:samples.gsod] w
WHERE w.station_number=s.USAF AND w.wban_number=s.WBAN 
GROUP BY w.month, w.year, w.station_number, s.LAT, s.LON;`

I tried to reference "max_temperature" to [publicdata:samples.gsod], but for whatever reason it is referencing it to [weather.stations]. Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The error clearly says that no such field exists.

Comment: To answer this it is strongly required to know structure of these tables. Could you show lists of fields or give a reference where it's possible to see it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying multiple tables in Big Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171776/querying-multiple-tables-in-big-query)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're trying to do a JOIN, but in BigQuery SQL, a comma-separated list of tables denotes a UNION ALL instead of a JOIN (yes it is strange; yes, we probably would change it if we could, but it might be too late at this point).

What you most likely want is:

```
SELECT w.station_number, s.LAT, s.LON, w.year, w.month, 
       avg(w.mean_temp) as [mean temp], max(w.max_temperature) as [max temp], 
       min(w.min_temperature) as [min temp], 
       avg(w.mean_visibility) as [avg visbility]
FROM [weather.stations] s, 
JOIN [publicdata:samples.gsod] w
ON w.station_number=s.USAF AND w.wban_number=s.WBAN 
GROUP BY w.month, w.year, w.station_number, s.LAT, s.LON;
```