# Bigquery how to query multiple tables of the same structure?

Tags: google-bigquery, multiple-tables

I have datasets of the same structure and i know I can query them like this, they are named by date:

```
SELECT column
FROM [xx.ga_sessions_20141019] ,[xx.ga_sessions_20141020],[xx.ga_sessions_20141021] 
WHERE column = 'condition';
```

However I actually want to query various months of this data... so instead of listing them all in the same way as above, is there syntax that you can use that looks like:

```
SELECT column
FROM [xx.ga_sessions_201410*] ,[xx.ga_sessions_201411*]
WHERE column = 'condition';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying multiple tables in Big Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171776/querying-multiple-tables-in-big-query)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions) section of the BigQuery query reference.  `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` or `TABLE_QUERY` will work for you here.  Something like:

```
SELECT column
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(xx.ga_sessions_,
                      TIMESTAMP('2014-10-19'),
                      TIMESTAMP('2014-10-21'))
WHERE column = 'condition';
```